# Why do I keep getting an error saying StandardPurchasingModule' does not exist in the current context?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to do a tutorial from unity (https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/analytics/integrating-unity-iap-your-game?playlist=17123) and I copied the code from here. However, I keep getting an error saying: The name `StandardPurchasingModule' does not exist in the current context

I can't figure out why this keeps happening. This is line I am getting the error on

```
var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());
```

Comment: Did you include `using UnityEngine.Purchasing;`?

Comment: Yes I did include this.

Answer (score 11):

It seem you need to install the Unity IAP by your own. Unity might skipped that step or you accidentally skipped it. who knows.. hahha

To fixed it, just go the folder 'UnityPurchasing' folder in 'Plugins' folder.
Then double click on the package Unity IAP. Import all and the problem solved. If it does fix your problem just try Dong Nguyen solution.

Answer (score 6):

For the more recent Unity IAP versions (> 3.0.0), there is no .unitypackage to import and there are no files / folders under the plugins folder.

I was getting the error because I was using an **assembly definition** and had only included **Unity.Purchasing** as a dependency. I needed to include **Unity.Purchasing.Stores** dll as well to get rid of that error.

Answer (score 5):

I have same problem.
I think this bug of unity. It not import all libarary we need, And I resolved.
I create new unity project, enable Unity Purchasing, and then I copy folder Plugins/UnityPurchasing of new project to problem project.

Answer (score 4):

You need install plugin after import Unity IAP.
[Look where is installer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAniy.png)

P.S. If you have errors after install plugin, you need delete demo scene and demo scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Just manually import Unity IAP and this will resolve the issue.